# When should I post on Meta Ask Ubuntu vs Meta Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, meta

I recently posted a question on the meta Stack Exchange site and realized that perhaps the question was better suited for the meta Ask Ubuntu site, and then realized I don't really know what the difference is between the two, as I am new to the meta sites.

That being said I was trying to use the tag `electorate-badge` which was available on the Meta Stack Exchange site, but not available on the Meta Ask Ubuntu site.

Any clarification would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

For questions about the system, either Meta is okay. We have plenty of people who have been using it for years.

For questions specifically about Ask Ubuntu (want to highlight a problem, ask us to do things differently, etc), here makes most sense but I'm sure there are occasions when Meta.SE makes sense too.

If you want to suggest a change to the underlying system (feature requests, reporting typos in badges or the help, etc), while SE staff do circulate around all the sites, you'll get a lot more feedback on Meta.SE.

---

Regarding badges and features *on Meta sites*, most sites have a cut-down feature-set. That is to say things available on the main site (reputation and various badges) are only available on the main site. Meta.SE is slightly different in that it *is* the main site. It has reputation and all those gubbins.

Comment: Meta.SE also has a rather rigid policy about duplicates - I know people who came very close to being question-banned after their first bold walk into that community.